# Low Search: search parameter conditional

Tags: low-search

**Situation**: I have a Low Search outputting my search results using the "search:field" parameter. This works.
In the publish form a user can add a Video EITER by submitting a youtube/vimeo link or pasting an embed code from another video service.

**Problem**: I would like to use the search param to only display entries that have either one of these fields set.

Something like: `search:my_field_video="not IS_EMPTY" OR search:my_field_embed="not IS_EMPTY"`

If I use conditionals in the output to check for the existence of there field values, the search results aren't correct (it'll say: 103 items when there are only 100 because 3 are counted but not shown).

Answer (score 1):

Combining tag parameters with OR is something that is not easily done in EE, as the whole paradigm for this is cumulative. Everywhere, parameters are combined with AND.

So, you'd have to work around it, for example by creating [a custom filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/create). Or, if you're OK with hardcoding the parameter, you could use a [SQL Parameter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/parameters#sql-params). Something like this:

```
entry_id="SELECT entry_id FROM exp_channel_data WHERE channel_id = 1 AND (field_id_X != '' OR field_id_Y != '');-1"
```

Where you'd have to replace X and Y with the appropriate field IDs, and make sure the `channel_id` is correct.